# How do I properly implement Google Play Service Achievements?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I've been searching for a couple of days, including on this website. What I have found would be useful, however I find that I'm unable to follow them correctly. The questions here have no answers either.

Firstly, when I attempt to add BasegameUtils to the project and import whats needed, Eclipse cannot find them. I don't understand why, because I have imported it and marked it as a library.

This is not helped by the fact that all of the examples have their mainactivity in the folder where the API is. I have already built a full application, and I do not understand where I'm supposed to put mine.

The whole thing is incredibly confusing, and any help, or examples would be lovely.

Comment: Have you tried the [Getting Started for Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart) guide? If so, what specifically did you have problems with? As it stands, this question is far too broad to answer.

Comment: @Tranis.7x I have looked at the documentation, yes. However, like my question, the documentation is very broad. I have gotten to add the library from the SDK, however it states that I need to use code such as:


 "Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), "my_achievement_id");"


I'm unsure of where to put this, and why. It does not thoroughly explain the usage of these, and that is why confuses me. Currently, I'm looking to place that call within a running code that also calls addPoints();. Would it work anywhere that I import the API?

Comment: Another question, when I attempt to import gms.* and com.google.(anything), Eclipse throws me an error. I added BaseGameUtils to my project and marked it as a library but it is not recognizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was not simple. The guides seem to favour Android Studio, which implement a script to create BaseGameUtils. The BaseGameUtild that I was importing with Eclipse was not the correct one. I ended up searching for a valid one, and downloaded it.

The second thing I was doing wrong was not updating the SDK to version 20. Now, with the Play Services Lib in the extras, I could import the updated version.

After that, I discovered that gms.*; actually must be written as com.google.android.gms..*;. With this in line, I am now able to properly implement everything.

Thank you to those who helped.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

You need to implement baseGameUtils as a library or module depending on your IDE.

```
public class Main extends BaseGameActivity
```

And then you call this to unlock the achievement.

```
Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), getString(YOUR_ACHIEVEMENT_CODE));
```

These code samples really helped me first time round.

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils

The tricky part isn't the code, it's the configuration of your project, make sure to check on the play developer console that you have set up your testing account properly and your achievement codes are correct etc.

Comment: There's one of my problems. When I import it, I cannot import it inside of another folder. Someone told me that I need to add android.jar to my project, so I will try that as well.

Comment: When I go to import this, even after doing what you said, Eclipse tells me that the two imports are unresolved. I do not understand why it cannot find the library.

Comment: Can I recommend Android Studio to you, using the Gradle build system is so much easier than eclipse. I haven't actually used game services in eclipse, only studio. And it was such a simple process to import it. If you are staying with eclipse, it could be something to do with your build path?

Comment: Have you followed the steps in on the home page of the repo? You may have missed this.


Right-click on BaseGameUtils, then click Properties
In the project properties window, click the Android section
Check the Is Library checkbox

Comment: Yes, it is marked as a library. I have never seen such a persistent issue with Eclipse. I am going to try updating the the latest SDK and Eclipse version to see if that works.

Comment: I will try out AS. From past experiences, I didn't like it too much. I like Eclipse because I'm used to it and still use it for other projects outside of Android.
I'll check in after trying it to see if that worked.

Comment: @Jesdon Atherton Posted the answer. :)